# numpy boolean indexing multiple conditions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a two dimensional numpy array and I am using python 3.5. I am starting to learn about Boolean indexing which is way cool. I can do this with my two dimensional array, arr. 
mask = arr > 127
arr[mask] = 0

This works perfect but now I am trying to change this logic to use boolean indexing

```
for x in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for y in range(arr.shape[1]):
        if arr[x,y] < -10:
            arr[x,y] = 0
        elif arr[x,y] < 15:
            arr[x,y] = arr[x,y] + 5
        else:
            arr[x,y] = 30
```

I tried multiple conditional operators for my indexing but I get the following error:

`ValueError: boolean index array should have 1 dimension boolean index array should have 1 dimension`.

I tried multiple versions to try to get this to work. Here is one try that produced the ValueError.

```
 arr_temp = arr.copy()
 mask = arry_temp < -10
 mask2 = arry_temp < 15
 mask3 = mask ^ mask3
 arr[mask] = 0
 arr[mask3] = arry[mask3] + 5
 arry[~mask2] = 30
```

I received the error on mask3. I am new to this so I know the code above is not efficient trying to work out it.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: `arr[arr < -10] = 0`, `arr[arr < 15] = arr[arr < 15] + 5` and `arr[arr >= 15] = 30`?

Comment: The problem with your question is that you're showing us the *old* code, and the error to the *new* code, without showing the actual *new* code that produces the error. That's not very practial, because we're having to guess what you actually wrote to get that error.

Comment: I think your mask creation could use some help : `mask1 = arr<-10
mask2 = ~mask1 & (arr<15)
mask3 = ~(mask1 | mask2)` and then using `mask1,2,3` to set `0, +5 and 30` values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might help.  Consider a numpy array of floating point values foo.

```
import numpy as np
foo=np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8])
```

foo yields

```
array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8])
```

This is how you get the values in foo > 0.3

```
foo[np.where( foo > 0.3)]
```

yields

```
array([0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8])
```

This is how to do the same with multiple conditions.  In this case, values > 0.3 and less than 0.6.

```
foo[np.logical_and(foo > 0.3, foo < 0.6)]
```

yields

```
array([0.4, 0.5])
```

**Alternatively using boolean mask array**

```
mask_1 = foo > 0.3
mask_2 = foo < 0.6
mask_3 = np.logical_and(mask_1, mask_2)
mask_3
```

Yields a boolean mask array

```
array([False, False, False,  True,  True, False])
```

Which you can then use to slice the array via

```
foo[mask_3]
```

Yields

```
array([0.4, 0.5])
```